# C# XNA - I want to access the Board(instance of a class) that this particular Block(instance of a class) exists in

Tags: c#, xna

I thought about it for a long time, and I couldn't come up with a better title. I'm not sure what specific thing I need to figure out in order to solve this problem. This is the code I have minus anything I think is unnecessary for this question.

```
static class GameManager
{
    public static List<Board> Boards = new List<Board>();
    // let's say there are 2 boards
}

class Board
{
    public Dictionary<Vector2, Block> Blocks = new Dictionary<Vector2, Block>();
    //each board has a bunch of blocks in it.
{

class Block
{
    //I want to access the Board that this particular Block exists in.
}
```

See, I used to have just one board, so if I was a block in the block class, and I wanted to access, say, the number of blocks in a board, I could just use `GameManager.Board.Blocks.Count`. I wanted to add multiplayer, so I made a list of boards each with their own set of blocks. Now I need to somehow make a block know which board it's in.

Is there maybe a way I can go backwards in terms of accessing different levels of code? For example, if I started at `GameManager`, I could go forward through levels by saying `GameManager.Boards[0].Blocks[new Vector2(0, 0)]` with a `.` for every level I go down. If I'm starting at the `Block` class, am I able to go up to access the particular instance of `Board` that the current instance of `Block` exists within? I don't want to turn this into an XY problem so what do you think I should do? It seems like storing and passing a variable that keeps track of the current board that's being updated is sloppy code because each block should already know which board it exists in since I did in fact initiate multiple boards each containing their own separate set of blocks. Do you think perhaps I need to nest the `Block` class within the `Board` class?

Answer (score 0):

Given your design, there is no *direct* way for a block to know which board its in. In general, this is a good thing. Why would a block *need* any knowledge of its board?

But, you could write this (as is):

```
var parent = GameManager.Boards.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Blocks.Values.Contains(this));
```

Now that's pretty inefficient, and not very pretty. You could also just pass the board *to* the block when you create it and hold it in a `parent` field of the `Block` class. This is **much** more speed efficient, at the cost of an extra variable per block.

In reality though, classes rarely if ever need to know about what is holding them. Think carefully to determine if this is *actually* a requirement for your game.

Comment: While your code and explanations are spot on, I'd like to point out one thing. You seem to put a lot of pressure on having classes not know anything about their "parents". I'd like to state that this VERY largely depends on the type of game you're making. For instance, if you've built the game structure on a sort of hierarchy structure, you'll be likely to have a Parent property on all objects, which is required, because upon (for example) drawing the child, it needs to know where its Parent is placed, so it knows where its "root" point is. Just an example.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard Undoubtedly there are valid use cases for children knowing about their parent. That said, in *general* (game or not) you usually can/should avoid needing that knowledge to reduce coupling. Thanks for the feedback!